# ListAdapter : Json data to be sent to spinner in android

Tags: android, json, arraylist, spinner, listadapter

Hi I created an activity, in that i want to get json data in spinner via List Adapter. How it possible please help me.

Using this code i get json data to Array List.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> officeList;   
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
    {
        jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        O_Id = jsonObj.getString("O_Id");
        O_Name = jsonObj.getString("O_Name");                           

        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
        contact.put("office_id", O_Id);
        contact.put("office_name", O_Name);                         
        officeList.add(contact);
    }
```

I want to get only "office_name" in the spinner.
How to attach `officeList` into spinner.

Comment: Ok @Shayanpourvatan, but how? Give me some tips.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955424/creating-a-spinner-from-an-arraylistobject

Comment: Are you working with getter setter method.

Comment: Thank you...My work is  done by using String Array, ArrayAdapter<String> and ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can make Custom Adapter and pass your ArrayList to that adapter constructor as a Parameter.

Something Like that..

```
   CustomAdapter cp = new CustomAdapter(YourActivityName.this,officeList); 
   spinner.setAdapter(cp);
```

for that you have also make one custom layout xml file in which your ***TextView*** will be.

Now ***CustomAdapter*** extebds with ***BaseAdapter***

and after that in getView() method you can get ***officename*** by

```
   String ofcname  = yourarraylist.get(position).get("office_name");
   txtview.setText(ofcname);
```

Comment: Thank you...My work is done by using String Array, ArrayAdapter<String> and ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hashmap get the values in the java pojo object and override `toString` method.

```
class MyOffice{

private int office_id;
private String office_name;

  @Override
   public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return office_name;
   }

}
```

and set the adapter to the spinner as `ArrayAdapter<MyOffice>`